# Why is OpenGL simple loop faster than Vulkan one?

Tags: opengl, vulkan

I have 2 graphics applications for OpenGL and Vulkan.

OpenGL loop looks something like this:

```
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

static int test = 0;

// "if" statement here is to ensure that there is no any caching or optimizations
// made by OpenGL driver (if such things exist),
// and commands are re-recorded to the buffer every frame

if ((test = 1 - test) == 0) {

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer1);
    glUseProgram(program1);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices_size);
    glUseProgram(0);
}
else {

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer2);
    glUseProgram(program2);
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, vertices_size);
    glUseProgram(0);
}

glfwSwapBuffers(window);
```

And Vulkan:

```
static uint32_t image_index = 0;

vkAcquireNextImageKHR(device, swapchain, 0xFFFFFFFF, image_available_semaphores[image_index], VK_NULL_HANDLE, &image_indices[image_index]);

vkWaitForFences(device, 1, &submission_completed_fences[image_index], VK_TRUE, 0xFFFFFFFF);

// VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_ONE_TIME_SUBMIT_BIT
vkBeginCommandBuffer(cmd_buffers[image_index], &command_buffer_bi);
vkCmdBeginRenderPass(cmd_buffers[image_index], &render_pass_bi[image_index], VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);
vkCmdEndRenderPass(cmd_buffers[image_index]);
vkEndCommandBuffer(cmd_buffers[image_index]);

vkResetFences(device, 1, &submission_completed_fences[image_index]);

vkQueueSubmit(graphics_queue, 1, &submit_info[image_index], submission_completed_fences[image_index]);

present_info[image_index].pImageIndices = &image_indices[image_index];

vkQueuePresentKHR(present_queue, &present_info[image_index]);

const static int max_swapchain_image_index = swapchain_image_count - 1;

if (++image_index > max_swapchain_image_index) {

  image_index = 0;
}
```

In the Vulkan loop there are no even rendering commands, just empty render pass. Validation layers are disabled.

OpenGL FPS is about 10500, and Vulkan FPS is about 7500 (with 8 swapchain images in use with VK_PRESENT_MODE_IMMEDIATE_KHR, less images make FPS lower).

Code is running on laptop with Ubuntu 18.04, discrete GPU Nvidia RTX 2060, Nvidia driver 450.66, Vulkan API version 1.2.133.

I know that OpenGL driver is highly optimized, but i can't imagine what else is to be optimized in Vulkan loop to make it faster than it is.

Are there some low-level linux driver issues? Or maybe Vulkan performance increase is accomplished only in much more complex applications (using multithreading e.g.)?

Comment: What exactly is the point of measuring how long it takes to do *nothing*? Your actual application will be doing something, so performance testing a case of doing nothing accomplishes... nothing.

Comment: If it is doing nothing, why is it slower than OpenGL loop that is doing some work? And if i insert commands ```vkCmdBindDescriptorSets``` and ```vkCmdBindVertexBuffers``` before ```vkCmdBeginRenderPass```, and ```vkCmdBindPipeline``` and ```vkCmdDraw``` before ```vkCmdEndRenderPass```, to draw the same geometry with the same shaders as OpenGL app, nothing happens, FPS remains ~7500.

Comment: You should also take into account that framerate is the wrong metric. Actual time is what matters. And the time difference between these is 0.038 ***micro*** seconds.

Comment: Thank you for comments. Yes, OpenGL average frame is 0.038 micro seconds faster. But what does it change? Sorry, i don't understand.

Comment: It's a matter of perception. The difference between 10500 and 7500 is 3000, which seems like a really large number. But in absolute terms, 0.038us is a tiny amount and thus not worth being concerned about.

Comment: So what possible implications could you derive from this "benchmark". So this is some micro benchmark of basically calling into the driver libraries in two different cases, and the result is not applicable to anything at all.

Comment: try replacing the api calls to their `vkGetDeviceProcAddr` equivalent. it may happen you could spare up that little 0.038us.

Comment: are you comparing rendering a triangle with opengl and doing a clear in vulkan?

Comment: I am comparing rendering a cube with both opengl and vulkan. And also doing a clear with vulkan. Framerates are almost the same. And i am aqcuiring all device-dependent functions with ```vkGetDeviceProcAddr```, not ```vkGetInstanceProcAddr```, do you mean this?

Comment: BTW your `image_index` handling seems wrong. You should pick the framebuffer and semaphore with the image index the `vkAcquireNextImageKHR` gives you, and **not** your sequentially increasing index.

Comment: @krOoze it seems that i can't use ```image_available_semaphores``` with index aqcuired with ```vkAcquireNextImageKHR```, because i can't know that index before and during calling ```vkAcquireNextImageKHR```. Am i wrong?

Comment: @DenisBelov Sure. Still, I am not convinced that your sync is correct. It is best to get a good ol' pen and paper and make a sync proof. E.g. how do you know on `vkAcquire` that the given semaphore is not already being signaled? The main problem though is that you pick the wrong framebuffer, and so you potentially write to a swapchain image that you have not even acquired.